# VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when Selecting Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with a Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when selecting a range.

I am still able to select rows (ie `Rows("21:21").select`) and to select ranges in other sheets of the same workbook. I do not believe the error is in the code. Maybe its some setting I am unaware of?

I have used the exact same code many times before but for some reason I cannot make it function in this sub (I have commented where the error occurs)...

```
Sub CopySheet1_to_PasteSheet2()

    Dim CLastFundRow As Integer
    Dim CFirstBlankRow As Integer

    'Finds last row of content
    Windows("Excel.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("C21").Select
         '>>>Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" Occurs
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    CLastFundRow = ActiveCell.Row
    'Finds first row without content
    CFirstBlankRow = CLastFundRow + 1

    'Copy Data
    Range("A21:C" & CLastFundRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    'Paste Data Values
    Sheets("PalTrakExport PortfolioAIdName").Select
    Range("A21").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Bring back to top of sheet for consistancy
    Range("A21").Select
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I need to get all fancy in my copying as the amount of rows will change frequently. Again, the below code has been used before without error... but not in this instance.

```
Dim CLastFundRow As Integer
Dim CFirstBlankRow As Integer

'Finds last row of content
Windows("Excel.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("C21").Select
     '>>>Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" Occurs
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
CLastFundRow = ActiveCell.Row
'Finds first row without content
CFirstBlankRow = CLastFundRow + 1
```

Comment: It's always best to avoid using Select : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 33):

Perhaps your code is behind Sheet1, so when you change the focus to Sheet2 the objects cannot be found? If that's the case, simply specifying your target worksheet might help:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Select
```

I'm not very familiar with how Select works because I try to avoid it as much as possible :-). You can define and manipulate ranges without selecting them. Also it's a good idea to be explicit about everything you reference. That way, you don't lose track if you go from one sheet or workbook to another. Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheet1_to_PasteSheet2()

    Dim CLastFundRow As Integer
    Dim CFirstBlankRow As Integer
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngStart As Range, rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range

    Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wksDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Finds last row of content
    CLastFundRow = wksSource.Range("C21").End(xlDown).Row
    'Finds first row without content
    CFirstBlankRow = CLastFundRow + 1

    'Copy Data
    Set rngSource = wksSource.Range("A2:C" & CLastFundRow)

    'Paste Data Values
    Set rngDest = wksDest.Range("A21")
    rngSource.Copy
    rngDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Bring back to top of sheet for consistancy
    wksDest.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Separating Copy from Past like it said in this answer did the trick for us. Thanks

Answer (score 29):

It's a bit late but might be helpful for future reference. I had just had the same issue and I think it's because the macro was placed at the worksheet level. Right click on the modules node on the VBA project window, click on "Insert" => "Module", then paste your macro in the new module (make sure you delete the one recorded at the worksheet level).

Comment: This seems to be exactly the problem! I was using a button recorded at the worksheet level, copied and pasted into a module and it worked amazingly! Thank you very much!

Comment: THANK YOU X10000! This was exactly my issue. I just wish I understood why this was an issue. All I'm doing is comparing dates between Cell A and Cell B and then changing a color. In Any case, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 16):

I as well had the same problem and nearly drove crazy. The solution was pretty unexpected.

My Excel is shipped out by default that I enter formulas in an Excel-Cell as followed:

```
=COUNTIF(Range; Searchvalue)
=COUNTIF(A1:A10; 7) 'Example
```

Please note, that parameters are separated with a semicolon`;`. Now if you paste exactly that string into a formula within VBA, for example like:

```
Range("C7").FormulaArray = "=COUNTIF(A1:A10; 7)" 'this will not work
```

You will get this 1004-error with absolutely no explanation. I spent hours to debug this.. All you have to do is replace all semicolon with commas.

```
Range("C7").FormulaArray = "=COUNTIF(A1:A10, 7)" 'this works
```

Comment: Please note, this answer might not actually solve this specific problem, but as this question was the only that went near my problem, I'm posting my answer here. Please comment or downvote, so that I have an incentive to later open my own question and place this answer there :-) will not happen now, I'm busy at work.

Comment: Man this is crazy, thank you SO MUCH. I have been blocked on hours on that problem. This is why I absolutely HATE VBA

Comment: I had similar issue than u, let me share my experience:
Cells(1,20)=(F20/1000 * G20/1000) * K20 * 1,2 -> this didn't work .
Cells(1,20)=(F20/1000 * G20/1000) * K20 * 1.2 -> this works.
And the only difference is that I replaced the COMMA in 1,2 to DOT. 
+1 for u to share your solution and helped to find my.

Comment: saved me many frustrating hours

Comment: @HowToTellAChild's example sounds like an internationalization issue, maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 9):

The same thing happened to me. In my case most of the worksheet was in protected mode (though the cells relevant to the macro were unlocked). When I disabled the protection on the worksheet, the macro worked fine...it seems VBA doesn't like locked cells even if they are not used by the macro.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find out the actual reason for this common error code: 1004. Edit your function/VBA code and run your program in debug mode to identify the line which is causing it. And then, add below piece of code to see the error,

```
On Error Resume Next
//Your Line here which causes 1004 error
If Err.Number > 0 Then
  Debug.Print Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
End If
```

Note:
Debug shortcut keys i use in PC:
Step Into (F8), Step Over (Shift + F8), Step Out (Ctrl + Shift + F8)

Answer (score 3):

Some operations in Excel are limited by available Memory. If you repeat the same process over and over it could produce a memory overflow and excel will not be able to repeat it anymore. This happened to me while trying to create several sheets in the same workbook.

Answer (score 2):

[You may receive a "Run-time error 1004" error message when you programmatically set a large array string to a range in Excel 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818808)

In Office Excel 2003, when you programmatically set a range value with an array containing a large string, you may receive an error message similar to the following:

> Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or operation-defined error.

This issue may occur if one or more of the cells in an array (range of cells) contain a character string that is set to contain more than 911 characters.

**To work around this issue, edit the script so that no cells in the array contain a character string that holds more than 911 characters.**

For example, the following line of code from the example code block below defines a character string that contains 912 characters:

```
Sub XLTest()
Dim aValues(4)

  aValues(0) = "Test1"
  aValues(1) = "Test2"
  aValues(2) = "Test3"

  MsgBox "First the Good range set."
  aValues(3) = String(911, 65)

  Range("A1:D1").Value = aValues

  MsgBox "Now the bad range set."
  aValues(3) = String(912, 66)
  Range("A2:D2").Value = aValues

End Sub
```

Other versions of Excel or free [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-excel/) like [Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code (For example if one was to want to copy cell data from `Sheet2` to `Sheet1`).

```
Sub Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate                    
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, FullPathLastColumn)).Copy_
Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Path2Row, Path2EndColumn + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer to include an explanation of how your code works and _please don't write it as if you're texting a friend_. If your not sure about how to answer questions on StackOverflow then please have a read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Cheers and happy answering!

Answer (score 2):

I could remove the error (Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or operation-defined error) by defining the counters as Single

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but it turns out I was just referencing a cell which was off the page {i.e. `cells(i,1).cut cells (i-1,2)`}

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to the sheet of db to get the first blank row, you could try this method.

```
Sub DesdeColombia ()    
  Dim LastRowFull As Long

  'Here we will define the first blank row in the column number 1 of sheet number 1:
  LastRowFull = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row

  'Now we are going to insert information
  Sheet1.Cells(LastRowFull, 1).Value = "We got it"    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem & fixed it applying these steps:

1. Unprotecting the sheet that I want to edit
2. Changing the range that I had selected by every single cell in the range (exploded)

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue during VBA development/debugging suddenly because some (unknown to me) function(ality) caused the cells to be locked (maybe [renaming of named references at some problematic stage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458931/1915920)).

**Unlocking the cells manually** worked fine:

Selecting all worksheet cells (`CTRL+A`) and unlock by **`right click -> cell formatting -> protection -> [ ] lock`** (may be different - translated from German: `Zellen formatieren -> Schutz -> [ ] Gesperrt`)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to loop on each sheet of a workbook.
To resolve it I did something like this

```
dim mySheet as sheet

for each mysheet in myWorkbook.sheets

    mySheet.activate
    activesheet.range("A1").select

    with Selection
    'any wanted operations here
    end with

next
```

And it worked just fine

I hope you can adapt it in your situation

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found that the individual that created the worksheet had several columns locked.  I removed the protection and everything worked as designed.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem and I solved by as below.
in macro have a variable called rownumber and initially i set it as zero. this is the error because no excel sheet contains row number as zero. when i set as 1 and increment what i want. 
now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue. After copying and pasting to a sheet I wanted the cursor/ selected cell to be A1 not the range that I just pasted into.

```
Dim wkSheet as Worksheet
Set wkSheet = Worksheets(<sheetname>)

wkSheet("A1").Select
```

but got a 400 error which was actually a 1004 error

You need to activate the sheet before changing the selected cell
this worked

```
Dim wkSheet as Worksheet
Set wkSheet = Worksheets(<sheetname>)

wkSheet.Activate
wkSheet("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add an additional fix since I had previously never encountered it:

A user of mine was running into this runtime error with an Excel workbook he pulls information from, but only on his desktop computer even though its hardware and software were nearly identical to his laptop (same amount of memory, OS, Office configuration, etc.).

It turned out that the monitor connected to his desktop computer was too big - the solution/work around was to open a blank Excel file, make the Excel window smaller, then open the file he was having issues with.

Since this was a file generated by a third-party - we could not edit/implement any of the previously suggested fixes, nor did changing the macro or protection settings do anything (and they were working on his laptop with the same settings anyway).