# Run-Time error 1004. Filtering on an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter based on an array. However, when I run the code I get a Run-time error 1004. AutoFilter method of Range class failed on my last line of code. Can anyone explain how to correct this? Thank you!

```
  Dim n As Long
    Dim r As Range

    With Sheets("Filter")
        n = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim ary(1 To n)
        For i = 1 To n
            ary(i) = .Cells(i, 1)
        Next i
    End With


    Worksheets("TempEE").Range("A1:AE100000").AutoFilter , Field:=8, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when Selecting Range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select)

Comment: As @cybermonkey is alluding to, just change `Worksheets("TempEE").Range("A1:AE100000").AutoFilter , Field:=8, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues` to `Worksheets("TempEE").Select: Range("A1:AE100000").AutoFilter , Field:=8, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: @cybermonkey - are you sure you linked to the right duplicate question? I don't see how that question applies.

Comment: @cybermonkey how is this an exact duplicate?  It appears, at least to me he is neither using `.Select` nor has he failed to qualify his ranges.

Comment: @Chris2015 - you have an extra `,` at the beginning of your `.AutoFilter` argument list. Chances are that this will fix it. There also could be a problem if your array is not Dimensioned with same datatype that Excel recognizes for the data in the column you are trying to filter. It's hard to say if that's the case without seeing the data (or what datatype `ary` is), but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: The linked thread is not using autofilter, how is it a duplicate?

Comment: I tried - Worksheets("TempEE").Select
Range("A1:AE100000").AutoFilter , Field:=8, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues - but am still getting same error...?

Comment: Perhaps my problem is the range in question is a table object. Could this be my issue?

Comment: You still have the errant `,` try this: ` `Worksheets("TempEE").Range("A1:AE100000").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: I tried...excluding the renegade "," I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Also tried - Worksheets("TempEE").Select
Worksheets("TempEE").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues - no luck

Comment: Is it the `Criteria1:=ary` that is causing the error?