VBA handling weird error related to copying chart
I am working on a macro that copies a chart from each worksheet to a temporary sheet. For some reason, the macro fails when trying to copy the 6th chart, and says

The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type

This occurs at cht.Copy, all the charts in the file are the exact same other than the data they are plotting.
For Each ws In exp.Worksheets
    i = i + 1
    Set temp = exp.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
    temp.Name = "chart" & i
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1)
    cht.Copy
    temp.Paste Destination:=temp.Range("A1")
    Set cht = temp.ChartObjects(1)
Next

The weird thing is that if I choose to debug and continue from the debugger, the correct plot is pasted anyways, so the copy doesn't really fail.
I've tried finding a fix for the error but could not find anything that worked, so at this point I'm trying to find a way to ignore the error.
I've tried using On Error Resume Next, which ignored the error but pasted nothing since the copy failed.
I've also tried using On Error GoTo [label] and placing the label on the line before cht.Copy, to try to force it to copy but it just throws the same error.
Any ideas on how to avoid the error being thrown or how to handle it properly?

This type of approach has worked pretty reliably for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582628/478884

Perhaps it is a timing issue, put a delay before the Paste using this delay subroutine - Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay: DoEvents: Next i: End Sub

Just add DoEvents after cht.Copy as @MT1 suggested and I think it should be fine. See THIS. You need to give time to excel to place the object in the clipboard

Thanks everyone for the help, adding DoEvents as @SiddharthRout suggested seems to have solved the issue. Cheers!
