Excel VBA image paste issue
I am creating a program that runs solver and then copy pastes the results of multiple runs to a summary page. Due to some bugs with excel I previously asked about on here, there is a loop to detect an error when trying to paste, then attempting to paste again up to 20 times.
In some cases, when excel finally doesn't send an error, the image will paste on the incorrect sheet. As you can see below, I am explicitly telling it to paste to "su" and then explicitly telling it what cell in "su" to paste to. Is this a behavior someone has seen and knows how to fix?
Sub chartCopy(seq)
Dim ua, udc, wa, wdc, su As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lastSheet As Integer
Dim Cht As ChartObject
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ua = wb.Worksheets("Unweighted Analysis")
Set udc = wb.Worksheets("Unweighted Data Checks")
Set wa = wb.Worksheets("Weighted Analysis")
Set wdc = wb.Worksheets("Weighted Data Checks")
Set su = wb.Worksheets("Summary Page")

k = 15
l = 1 + (seq - 1) * 11
    
j = 0

If seq <> 4 Then
    lastSheet = 6
Else
    lastSheet = 4
End If
For i = 3 To lastSheet
    For Each Cht In wb.Worksheets(i).ChartObjects
        Debug.Print Cht.Name
        If i = 3 Then
            Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = ua.Range("DF16").Value
        ElseIf i = 5 Then
            Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = wa.Range("DG16").Value
        End If
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Cht.CopyPicture
        
        Do While x < 20
            On Error Resume Next
            su.Paste su.Cells(k, l)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Paste failed", x, Err.Number, Err.Description
                DoEvents
                x = x + 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        k = k + 25
        j = j + 1
    Next Cht
    If i = 4 Then
        k = k + 10
    End If
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Call sizeImg

ua.Range("F3:K6").Copy
su.Cells(4, l).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
If seq <> 4 Then
    wa.Range("F3:K6").Copy
    su.Cells(141, l).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub


While it will negatively impact the speed of execution of your procedure, an alternative to the clipboard is to export each chart, and then insert each on the respective target sheet. btw in your line Dim ua, udc, wa, wdc, su As Worksheet only su is of type Worksheet (i.e. it should be Dim ua as Worksheet, udc as Worksheet, wa as Worksheet, wdc as Worksheet, su As Worksheet)

You should reset x for each iteration of i, otherwise you risk skipping the Paste step once the value of x is >20

Error is 1004, Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data.

On which line ?

Happens during the paste operation. Seems to usually be the udc or wdc sheet and always the 3rd figure of 3 on those sheets. Those pages are just 3 charts that reference ua or wa. Nothing else on them.

Note your Exit Do skips the On Error Goto 0 line, so you're potentially missing some errors once that happens.  I like to pull that "paste/retry" out into a separate method to help avoid that kind of problem and to keep your main logic more compact. E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582628/478884

Thanks everyone. I moved the loop to a sub like Tim suggested, defined the rest of the worksheets like Spectral suggested. This helped reduce the frequency of the errors. It kept pasting on the wrong page, so I then reluctantly added a wb.Activate right before my paste and it worked. Seems like the wb.Paste command was trying to use the active sheet instead of the specified sheet for some reason. It is now working.

Some suggestions for refactoring a bit:
Option Explicit

Sub chartCopy(seq)
    Dim ua, udc, wa, wdc, su As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastSheet As Integer
    Dim Cht As ChartObject
    Dim k As Long, l As Long, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ua = wb.Worksheets("Unweighted Analysis")
    Set udc = wb.Worksheets("Unweighted Data Checks")
    Set wa = wb.Worksheets("Weighted Analysis")
    Set wdc = wb.Worksheets("Weighted Data Checks")
    Set su = wb.Worksheets("Summary Page")
    
    k = 15
    l = 1 + (seq - 1) * 11
    j = 0
    
    lastSheet = IIf(seq <> 4, 6, 4)
    
    For i = 3 To lastSheet
        For Each Cht In wb.Worksheets(i).ChartObjects
            Debug.Print Cht.Name
            If i = 3 Or i = 5 Then
                Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = _
                   IIf(i = 3, ua.Range("DF16").Value, wa.Range("DG16").Value)
                DoEvents 'let the chart update...
            End If
            Cht.CopyPicture
            'paste succeeds?
            If Not PastePicRetry(su.Cells(k, l)) Then
                MsgBox "Paste failed for chart '" & Cht.Name & "' on sheet '" & _
                         wb.Worksheets(i).Name & "'", vbExclamation
                'Exit Sub 'exit here?
            End If
            
            k = k + 25 + IIf(i = 4, 10, 0)
            j = j + 1
        Next Cht
    Next i
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Call sizeImg
    
    CopyValues ua.Range("F3:K6"), su.Cells(4, l)
    If seq <> 4 Then CopyValues wa.Range("F3:K6"), su.Cells(141, l)
    
End Sub

'Copy values from `fromRange` to `toRange`
Sub CopyValues(fromRange As Range, toRange As Range)
    With fromRange
        toRange.Cells(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub

'Try to paste in range `rng` - retry up to 20 times
'  Return True if paste succeeds
Function PastePicRetry(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Do While i < 20
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.PasteSpecial
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Paste failed", i
            DoEvents
        Else
            PastePicRetry = True
            Exit Function
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Function

