# Picture will intermittently not paste

Tags: excel, vba, image, error-handling, paste

I'm getting an intermittent error (1004 Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data) upon trying to paste an image in Excel as part of a larger VBA code.  It's strange because it's only happening some of the time and I haven't been able to identify why.  The error handling is also not working, the code is breaking on the paste line.

```
picTab.range("imageRNG").Copy

On Error GoTo picProblem:  
     picTab.Pictures.Paste  
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Can't you just use [`Range.CopyPicture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copypicture)?

Comment: The same thing is happening with range.copypicture  - intermittently breaking on paste.

Comment: I'm guessing a clipboard issue.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea how to fix or identify the issue if it's with the clipboard?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60063795/run-time-error-1004-microsoft-excel-cannot-paste-the-data/60065424#60065424

Comment: I also have same issue, finally i found the solution from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40595546/900284