# VBA insert an image multiple times without copy,paste

Tags: excel, vba

Little bit of an odd question here.

On one of my excel sheets, I generate a pdf document.

The code runs by adding in segments of tables as required and manually setting a page break as needed so that a table isnt spread of a single page. (most tables are 5-10 rows)

at the bottom of each page, there is enough rows left over to insert an image. the image is just a few squares and a text box grouped together to provide a disclaimer and a signature box.

currently I have been using the

```
Sheets(...).shapes(...).copy
sheets(...).cells(...).pastespecial paste:=xlpasteall
```

with a few

```
doevents
```

to try make sure it runs correctly.

I keep running into the issues of 800401d0 method
copy' of object 'shape' failed and error 1004 pastespecial method of range class failed.

I tthought it may have been becuase i did not have the doevents code but that has not remedied the situation.

I believe having the grouped shape saved as a single image embedded in the workbook may be easier so that I may use insert rather than copy.

the problem is I do not know how to go about this.

I could save the shapes as an image outside the worksheet, but when i do this, the quality drops and the text becomes blurry.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Fr the paste part maybe look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60063795/run-time-error-1004-microsoft-excel-cannot-paste-the-data/60065424#60065424

Comment: Hi Tim. I saw the code you posted and am confused as to where i put it into my code. I am not to familiar with dealing with errors. so i paste your sub in to my sheet and then have in my sub "onerror go to pastepicretry"?

Answer (score 1):

I've had random odd problems pasting images in Excel, typically when running in a loop, and retrying the paste often succeeds, so you can try something like this, where the paste is retried until it succeeds (or a fixed number of tries still fail...)

```vb
Sub CopySomeThings()
    '...
    '...
    Thisworkbook.Sheets("source").Shapes("CopyThis").Copy
    PastePicRetry Thisworkbook.Sheets("destination").Range("A50")
    'etc etc
End Sub



'paste problem fix: keep trying until it works or for 20 tries
Sub PastePicRetry(rng As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Do While i < 20
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.PasteSpecial
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Paste failed", i
            DoEvents
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the response. I cannot seem to get it to work. I believe it is because my range refernce isnt an exact cell but instead it is calculated. so my cell in this example is cells(x-10,2). is there a way to convert this into a range suitable reference? thanks.

Comment: What does it do instead of work?  Cells() is equivalent to Range() as long as x is valid

Comment: Hi Tim, I found the issue and fixed it. Your solution appears to be working. thank you so much.