# VBA Paste Special Method of Range Class Failed - intermittent occurence

Tags: vba

I've written code to read in a data file, create a plot, and then copy the plot and paste it as a picture onto another worksheet in the same workbook.  The code does this for multiple data files.

Below is the portion of the code where the problem occurs:

```
Sheets("RawData").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

Worksheets(LogSheetName).Activate
Range("A1").Activate
Selection.Offset(27 * (ifile - 1), 0).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial format:="Picture (JPEG)", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

The problem is that intermittently I get an error:  Paste Special Method of Range Class Failed. It fails on the last line. If I re-run the code with the same set of data files it will fail a different number of times and the files it fails on will be different.  So, the actual data file does not matter.  It is a problem that occurs randomly. When an error occurs I can click debug and then the run arrow to get it going again - and then the code goes on to execute everything correctly.  This is the only way I can effectively process all the files I need to get through.  But it means I have to babysit the code until it is finished.

I am out of things to try.

Comment: This typically works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67173303/478884  Re-try until the paste succeeds.