Excel VBA - Unable to get the Paste property of the Pictures class
I have the following VBA code snippet. The macro is erroring out with the "Unable to get the Paste property of the Pictures class" message on the line indicated below.
I am trying to copy all the charts on sheet "Source" and paste them as a picture in sheet "Destination". It is copying quite a few of the charts, but then errors out.
For Each chartObj In wsSrc.ChartObjects
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Source").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartObj.Name).Activate
    DoEvents
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    DoEvents
    Sheets("Destination").Select
    Range("G" & topShift).Select
    DoEvents
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select ' LINE THAT IS ERRORING OUT
    DoEvents

    topShift = topShift + 29
Next chartObj

I've tried a few other things that I've found online including trying to paste directly when I get the range, but I still get an error message.

I find running copy/paste with pictures in a loop often runs into problems - you can trap the error and retry.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67173303/478884

Not sure why this feels wrong to do in my gut- but it definitely worked. Thanks for the response, Tim.

Have you tried taking out the ".Select" on the line you said is erring out?  Also, get rid of all those DoEvents.  They just hog up processor cycles.

A loop like this should work fine, and used to in older versions of Excel.  A few years ago it started breaking and it's been that way ever since.  Re-trying the paste on error has always worked for me though. It's not pretty but it's a good workaround.

Sub test()


Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim chartObj As ChartObject
Dim topShift As Long

    Set wsSrc = Sheets("Source")
    Set wsDest = Sheets("Destination")
    topShift = 1  ' Starting row for paste position
    
    For Each chartObj In wsSrc.ChartObjects
        ' Copy chart as picture
        chartObj.Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    
        ' Paste in Destination sheet at specified range
        wsDest.Paste Destination:=wsDest.Range("G" & topShift)
        
        ' Increment top position for the next chart
        topShift = topShift + 29
    Next chartObj

End Sub


Hi Michal, thanks for the response.
Your code seems intuitive - however, now none of the images get copied over and I get following error -
Method 'CopyPicture' of object '_Chart' failed.

I used this code (simular as Michal's principle) and works for me:
Sub CopyChartToOtherSheet()
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim rowCounter As Integer

rowCounter = 1

Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
   
For Each chartObj In sourceSheet.ChartObjects
    chartObj.Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    targetSheet.Cells(rowCounter, 1).PasteSpecial
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 15
Next
End Sub

