Excel Chart copy paste issues
I have a code that is attempting to copy multiple charts from solution pages and paste them to a summary page. Th code works, but constantly throws errors in excel. If I click debug and then click run, it will continue on and do exactly what I want.
The errors are completely random, don't always happen in the same order, sometimes don't happen at all. Sometimes I will get 5 errors, sometimes 1, sometimes 10. Running the exact same thing with no changes.
The errors are:
"The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type."
"Method 'Paste' of object'_Worksheet' failed"
There was a third that I can't remember or replicate now. Will update if it happens again.
Any thoughts?
Dim ua, udc, wa, wdc, su As Worksheet
Set ua = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unweighted Analysis")
Set udc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unweighted Data Checks")
Set wa = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weighted Analysis")
Set wdc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weighted Data Checks")
Set su = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary Page")

i = 1
j = 0
k = 15
l = 2
count = 1
While i < 11
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    j = j + 1
    
    If i < 3 Then
        ua.ChartObjects(j).Copy
      
        If i = 2 Then
            j = 0
        End If
        
    ElseIf i < 6 Then
        udc.ChartObjects(j).Copy
        
        If i = 5 Then
            j = 0
        End If
        
    ElseIf i < 8 And seq <> 4 Then
        wa.ChartObjects(j).Copy
        
        If i = 7 Then
            j = 0
        End If
        
    ElseIf i < 11 And seq <> 4 Then
       wdc.ChartObjects(j).Copy
        
        If i = 10 Then
            j = 0
        End If
    End If
    
    DoEvents
    su.Paste su.Cells(k, l)
    
    'With su.Cells(k, l).PasteSpecial.xlPasteAll
    '    .Left = su.Cells(k, l).Left
    '    .Top = su.Cells(k, l).Top
    '    .Width = 500
    'End With
    k = 15 + (i) * 25
    i = i + 1
Wend
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
l = l + count * 11
count = count + 1

Update:
I changed the code up a bit to handle the loop with a For Each instead of the mess I posted above. Still getting the same issues.
i swapped these loops to a for each command to clean it up. still getting same errors using that loop.
j = 0
k = 15
For i = 3 To 6
    For Each Cht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).ChartObjects
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Debug.Print Cht.Name
        Cht.Copy
        su.Paste su.Cells(k, l)
        k = k + 25
        j = j + 1
    Next Cht
Next i


i swapped these loops to a for each command to clean it up. still getting same errors using that loop.
j = 0
For i = 3 To 6
For Each Cht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).ChartObjects
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Debug.Print Cht.Name
Cht.Copy
su.Paste su.Cells(k, l)
k = 15 + (j) * 25
j = j + 1
Next Cht
Next i

Please don't post code in the comments, edit your question and include your new code there.

For the pasting issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065424/478884

@TimWilliams that did the trick! thanks!

@TimWilliams is right there are several nasty potential race conditions in Excel graph plotting used from VBA that appeared in XL2007 and have never quite been fixed. Things like trying to plot points before the axes are established and cut/paste slightly mangled structures. A strategically placed small delay usually fixes it. Typically the code works fine most of the time but goes haywire if the wind it in the wrong direction. It always works perfectly in debug mode only full speed execution fails. You can end up with spurious file size increase from orphaned metadata too.
