# VBA Basic Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a pretty complicated VBA macro on Excel, but for some reason it keeps giving me an error. I have no idea why, considering how simple the particular portion of the code is, and I cannot see anything wrong with it.

Here is the code:

```
Sub hello()
     Sheets("Sheet2").Select
     Range("A3").Select
End Sub
```

Yep, that's literally it. I have no idea why that is giving me an error, but I keep getting

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error".

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Which line raises the error? Is the workbook protected?

Comment: Why must you `Select` that cell and worksheet?

Comment: Do you actually have a **Worksheet** (not a chart sheet or macro sheet) named `Sheet2`?

Comment: If you replace that with `msgbox Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Value`, does it still throw an error? Make sure you have a sheet named `Sheet2` in that workbook.  Also, where is your macro stored?

Comment: if you have a foreign langage setting in your office, "Sheet2" will be replaced accordingly to it.

Comment: @BruceWayne, there is certainly a sheet named Sheet2. If I do that I do not get an error stored. And I am not sure what you mean by where is it stored.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, yes it is a worksheet. In my more complicated application of the macro type of command its a little more difficult, but I am even trying with just a brand new excel file, with the standard sheets sheet1 sheet2 and sheet3 automatically in there

Answer (score 2):

Your code worked for me in a brand new workbook (Excel 2010).

There are a bunch of suggestions here:
[VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when Selecting Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select)

Comment: this is best suited as a comment, not an answer

Comment: I don't have enough points to post a comment yet but thought I could help :-)

Comment: now you do, I think :)

Comment: nah...it says 50 points...eventually :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `Activate` on a sheet, not `Select`:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
```

Comment: `Activate` and `Select` work just the same in this case.

Comment: And you want to avoid them both anyhow, unless you actually need a specific sheet showing.