# Merge content of two Excel file using VB macro Code

Tags: vba, excel

how to merge content of two Excel file using VB macro Code .

```
Sub GetSheets() 
Dim temp As String 
Path = "C:\Users\....\ Desktop\Excel combine\" 
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx") 

Do While Filename "" Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True 

temp = ActiveWorkbook.Name ActiveSheet.Name = temp 

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(temp).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Workbooks(Filename).Close 

Filename = Dir() 
Loop 

End Sub
```

The code what i am getting online is not meeting the requirement.

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you looking at combining to worksheets(Sheet1,Sheet2)  data into a single workbook (sheet1 and sheet2)

Comment: I have two separate excel sheet ,i want to merge both the excel in to one excel ...say 1.xls and 2.xls so i need to append the data of 2.xls to 1.xls

Comment: @siva: can you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will Copys Entire Sheet1 of WorkBook1 and places to WorkBook2 after Sheet1

```
Sub CopySheet_From_WB1_To_WB2()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

   Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Desktop\1.xlsx")
   Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("sheet1") 'replece 'Sheet1' with your sheet name
   Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Desktop\2.xlsx")
   'Copying WorkBook1's Sheet1 to Workbook2 after Sheet1
    ws1.Copy After:=wb2.Sheets("Sheet1") 'replece 'Sheet1' with your sheet name

   wb1.Save
   wb1.Close

   wb2.Save
   wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Below Code will copy used cells values from Sheet1 of Workbook1 and paste after last used row of Sheet1 of Workbook2

```
Sub CopySheet1Data_to_Sheet2()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Desktop\1.xlsx")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("sheet1") 'replece 'Sheet1' with your sheet name
    ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

    Selection.Copy
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\..\Desktop\2.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws2.Activate
    lastUsedRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    ws2.Cells(lastUsedRow + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    wb1.Save
    wb1.Close

    wb2.Save
    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siva,but i am running it i am getting application object error

Comment: Can you please specify the line of code which is giving error? Also which code either 1st or second

Comment: I am getting error in the 7th line  of the code i.e... Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Desktop\1.xlsx")

Comment: Di you replace the file path with your first workbook path?. If not please do. Please change sheet names as per your needs

Comment: Now i am getting at this line ..Set SourceDataRange = ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))

Comment: before this line add ws1.Activate and try.Please post the exact error details.So that it will be easy to address. I have tried both the codesin my machine.Every thing work fine.

Comment: i have added but still getting the same error ,Run time error :1004,application defined or object defined error

Comment: its working pretty well in my machine.Im not able figure it out why it that happening.Doues your source sheet have data?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? Is it 2003? Also see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select

Comment: i did not get that,i am using Excel 2007

Comment: Well can you please post the source and destination dummy sample sheets

Comment: ACCOUNT_ID A_NUMBER
sona   juhi
sona12   rupa454 i have put this in both the sheets

Comment: Seems nothing wrong with data. Im not sure what else could be the reason.

Comment: what error 1004 error you said earlier or some thing else?

Comment: still the same erroe is thrown

Comment: Im Sorry this is all i can suggest as of now. its working for the sample work books that  im using. Not sure why is it not working for you.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help

Comment: If you can share the Worknbooks you are using please do. I will give a try

Comment: the code will work  fine if we will replace it with this line,  ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

Comment: That's Great!!! Finally it worked.I hope it served what you are looking for

Comment: if i have different number of columns in the second sheet,then how can we achieve the same??

Comment: Above code will work fine even if it has different columns, as it blindly copy pastes details from one sheet to another. If you have any specific conditions to be met then you may have to customize the code according to your need

Comment: ya it is working fine but header of the excel sheet is also coming ,how can we remove that?

Comment: That's because you are using `ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select ` for copying the content from sheet1.So header row is also copied there, just replace it with `ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select `