# VBA "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when protect a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm writing a VBA macro that protects another workbook when user clicks a button and open it via current workbook. I got "Application-defined or Object-defined error". I looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select) and made sure that the workbook that needs to be opened is unprotected. But the error still occurs. Please help. Thanks!

```
Sub LockModelParInput()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Workbooks.Open (ModelParVarClusLocalPath & "\" & ProN & "_ModelParameter_UserInput.xlsx")
Set wbk = Workbooks(ProN & "_ModelParameter_UserInput.xlsx")
wbk.Activate
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Model_Rule")
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="VIF Cut Off Level 2", _
    Range:=Range("C4") *'error occurs on this line*
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="p_value stay", Range:= _
    Range("D4")
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Trend Threshold", Range _
    :=Range("E4")
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="r_var_ks_penalize", Range _
    :=Range("B10")
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="fast backward", Range:= _
    Range("C16")
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="locked forward", Range:= _
    Range("C17")
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="enhanced stepwise", Range _
    :=Range("C18")
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="traditional backward", _
    Range:=Range("C19")
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="sas stepwise", Range:= _
    Range("C21")
    .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify your `Range` calls. All of the `Range:=Range` in the `With` block should be `Range:=.Range`.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the problem - just test it still doesn't work. Also anything within With block is directly copied over from macro record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check to see if the edit range's title has already been used - they can't be duplicated.  Just knock up a quick function like this to iterate them:

```
Private Function EditRangeExists(Sh As Worksheet, Title As String) As Boolean
    With Sh.Protection
        Dim found As AllowEditRange
        For Each found In .AllowEditRanges
            If found.Title = Title Then
                EditRangeExists = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

...then check to make sure you're not attempting to add duplicates.  I'd use a small wrapper for the test to make your code cleaner:

```
Private Sub TryAddProtectionRange(Title As String, Target As Range)
    With Target
        If EditRangeExists(Target.Parent, Title) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .Parent.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title, Target
    End With
End Sub
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Sub LockModelParInput()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(ModelParVarClusLocalPath & "\" & ProN & _
              "_ModelParameter_UserInput.xlsx")
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Set Sh = wbk.Worksheets("Model_Rule")
    With Sh
        TryAddProtectionRange "VIF Cut Off Level 2", .Range("C4")
        TryAddProtectionRange "p_value stay", .Range("D4")
        'Etc.
        .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

I'd add some sort of error handling and/or have `TryAddProtectionRange` return a `Boolean` for success also.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that I did have duplicate protect range name - when I open the excel file using the macro for the first time, I saved it. Thus I have the protection range saved in the excel already and that' s why I can't open it again. Thanks a lot.