# Excel 2013 - 1004 Run-time error Refresh Query Table

Tags: vba, excel, odbc, runtime-error

Have been troubleshooting this one for weeks and so far, no resolutions have worked.  I have tried many solutions, including:

- Option Explicit
- removing BackgroundQuery = False
- AutoFilterMode = False

What is strange in my case is, on two computers running the same version of Excel and using the same version of ODBC driver, on Computer 1, all queries work and on Computer 2, it gives the run-time error.  The issue is, soon Computer 1 will be gone so I need to get Computer 2 working.

The other thing that is really odd is that Computer 2 does successfully connect and retrieve info in the same subroutine!  So query 1 works but query 2 gives the runtime error.

Running on Computer 2 in same Excel file, here is query 1:

```
SELECT  COUNT(ADM_APP_INFO.APP_NUM)
FROM 
 SCHEMA.TABLE TABLE
WHERE (TABLE.QUEUE  = 'QNAME' AND TABLE.PARAM = 'D' 
AND TABLE.DATE_ENT >= '1/1/2016')
```

which works and pulls info.  Query 2, which has a non-zero count is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(ACCT_NUM) FROM SCHEMA.DAILY_RUN WHERE DAILY_RUN.ACCT_NUM_FLAG = 0 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Yet it **does** work when on Computer 2 when query 2 has no WHERE clause.  Both of these queries work on Computer 1 but Query 2 with WHERE clause gives the error on Computer 2.

I even copy the working Excel file on Computer 1 to Computer 2 and get the error only on Computer 2.  These points suggest there isn't Any suggestions?

For reference, here is the With block I am using:

```
With Worksheets("Template").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="ODBC;DSN=Connect32;UID=UserName;;HOST=111.111.11.111;PORT=xxxx;SUBSYS=xxxx;DBTY=DB2;PLAN=xxxx ", _
    Destination:=Range("D5"))
    .CommandText = Range("Query!A1:A1").Value
    '.Name = "Query from MS Access Database"
    .FieldNames = False
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = True
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: what about copying failing excel file from computer #2 to computer #1 and running it there?

Comment: found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select#17982430

Comment: Hi jsotola, yes I tried that as well and it works again on Computer 1 while failing on Computer 2 - thanks but the link you suggested does a copy-paste but does not appear to address this issue...

Comment: here is another possibility: something is wrong with query #2 , something is wrong with computer #1 and computer #2 is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like I got a birthday present as one of my colleagues was able to resolve this.

Turns out my ODBC driver, as some of you may have suspected, was not configured the exact same way on both systems.  In my case, I needed to add the database name under the AlternateID setting under the Advanced tab.

Even fully qualifying the table names in the queries doesn't help without this step.  Hope this helps others out there facing this seemingly bizarre issue!