# How To Split Excel Rows into Two Sheets After Inputting Percentage

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a data set of 100 (or 999 / any random numbers) and I wish to extract X% (x can range between 1-99) of rows after I put it on a pop out dialog box.

```
#   Header  Header 2
1     A       Z
2     2       Y
3     C       X
4     D       3
5     E 
6     F       d
7       
8     H       1
9     I       8
10    J       9
```

Ideally, I wish to have an output of 2 new worksheets as below after I key in 20 in the pop out box.

[Output Workbook 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfO9q.png)

[Output Workbook 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX0lg.png)

Conditions to be considered:

1. The total number of rows & columns can be even or odd
2. The sheet name may vary for different workbook.
3. It should be able to save in master macro-enabled excel and use across.

I modified the codes from Joe's (Thanks!) but my workbook appears to crash on the bold line.

```
    Public Sub SplitWbByPercentage()
    Dim inputNum As Long
    Dim firstColumn As Long
    Dim headerRow As Long
    Dim cutoffRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim startingRows As Long
    Dim beforeWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim afterWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    inputNum = InputBox("Please enter First File Percentage: ")

    Set wbOrig = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ThisSheet = wbOrig.ActiveSheet

    firstColumn = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Column
    headerRow = 1
    lastRow = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + headerRow
    startingRows = lastRow - headerRow 'for the headers
    cutoffRow = Round(startingRows * (inputNum / 100), 0) + headerRow

    Set beforeWorksheet = Worksheets.Add()
    Set afterWorksheet = Worksheets.Add()

    beforeWorksheet.Rows(headerRow).EntireRow.Value = ThisSheet.Rows(headerRow).EntireRow.Value
    afterWorksheet.Rows(headerRow).EntireRow.Value = ThisSheet.Rows(headerRow).EntireRow.Value


    For x = headerRow + 1 To cutoffRow
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        **beforeWorksheet.Rows(x).EntireRow.Value = ThisSheet.Rows(x).EntireRow.Value**

        wb.SaveAs wbOrig.Path & "\Data 1" & WorkbookCounter
        wb.Close
    Next

    For x = cutoffRow + 1 To lastRow
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        afterWorksheet.Rows(headerRow + x - cutoffRow).EntireRow.Value = ThisSheet.Rows(x).EntireRow.Value
        wb.SaveAs wbOrig.Path & "\Data 2" & WorkbookCounter
        wb.Close
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with [`excel-vba`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba), I'm going to assume you are at least familiar with macros, so I came up with a macro that does what you want.

**Edit** - Updating code based on additional requirements. New code to pop up an input box and then split the data into two new workbooks, leaving the original alone.

**Edit 2** - Updating code based off of provided sample file. New code copies over the entire worksheet and then deletes rows out (versus desired rows over) to help with memory usage within Excel.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SplitWbByPercentage()
    Dim wbOrig As Workbook
    Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbOutput1 As Workbook
    Dim wsOutput1 As Worksheet
    Dim wbOutput2 As Workbook
    Dim wsOutput2 As Worksheet
    Dim inputNum As Long
    Dim firstColumn As Long
    Dim headerRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim cutoffRow As Long
    Dim x As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    inputNum = InputBox("Please enter First File Percentage: ")

    Set wbOrig = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ThisSheet = wbOrig.ActiveSheet

    firstColumn = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Column
    headerRow = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Row
    lastRow = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + headerRow

    rowCount = lastRow - headerRow 'for the headers
    cutoffRow = Round(rowCount * (inputNum / 100), 0) + headerRow

    ' Output Workbook 1
    ThisSheet.Copy
    Set wbOutput1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsOutput1 = wbOutput1.Worksheets(1)
    wsOutput1.Range(wsOutput1.Rows(cutoffRow + 1), wsOutput1.Rows(lastRow)).Delete
    wbOutput1.SaveAs wbOrig.Path & "\Data 1"
    wbOutput1.Close

    ' Output Workbook 2
    ThisSheet.Copy
    Set wbOutput2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsOutput2 = wbOutput2.Worksheets(1)
    wsOutput2.Range(wsOutput2.Rows(headerRow + 1), wsOutput2.Rows(cutoffRow)).Delete
    wbOutput2.SaveAs wbOrig.Path & "\Data 2"
    wbOutput2.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to modify the code as below, however I hit the error "subscript out of range". Can advise? Thanks

```Public Sub SplitByPercentage()
    Dim inputNum As Long
    inputNum = InputBox("Please enter % from 1 to 99: ")

    Dim startingWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set startingWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim firstColumn As Long
    firstColumn = startingWorksheet.UsedRange.Column

    Dim headerRow As Long
    Dim cutoffRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    headerRow = 1```

Comment: It looks like you comment got cut off. What line of code is being highlighted when you get the "subscript out of range" error?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I am new to Excel VBA. The "subscript out of range" appears at line `Set startingWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")` Could it be the reference?

Comment: Most likely it is caused by your workbook not having a sheet called "Sheet1". Just change the text inside the quotes to the name of the sheet where your data is and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Joe, I try to edit the codes as above, can help to check please as I would like it to make a new workbook without editing the original workbook. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joe, I get Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" on line `wsOutput1.Rows(x).EntireRow.Value = ThisSheet.Rows(x).EntireRow.Value`. Any idea why?

Comment: Without having your actual workbook, it is almost impossible for me to say (as Excel/VBA errors are way too generic). If you want to give me a copy (through Dropbox/OneDrive/etc), I can take a look. Otherwise, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select) and see if any of the suggested answers can solve the issue.

Comment: @Xon - I just updated the code. It probably was having issues iterating through all of the rows in your massive file. I ran the updated code against your file and it worked perfectly fine.