# getElementsBy() extract text

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I'm really new to `VBA` and I've been trying to get the value below the Column "Impuesto".

I'm getting error 438. I still don't quite understand how to refer to a certain part of the web page.

```
Sub extract()

Dim myIE As Object
Dim myIEDoc As Object
Dim element As IHTMLElement

Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

myIE.Visible = False

myIE.navigate "https://zonasegura1.bn.com.pe/TipoCambio/"

While myIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
 Set myIEDoc = myIE.document


Range("B1") = myIEDoc.getElementsByID("movimiento")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `getElementsByID`. If you actually wanted to locate by ID, the call is `getElementByID` (note non-plural) which returns a single element, not a collection of elements. In any event, it seems you do not actually need to locate by ID at all but by class name with `getElementsByClassName` which is plural and returns a collection. (as described in the answer below by @PaulChu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below script. It should fetch you the data you are after. When the execution is done, you should find the value in Range("A1") in your spreadsheet.

```
Sub Get_Quote()
    Dim post As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://zonasegura1.bn.com.pe/TipoCambio/"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set post = .document.querySelector(".movimiento span.l2.valor")
        [A1] = post.innerText
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, after executing the script if you do not get any result, be sure to check manually whether you can see the value in that webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You need `getElementsByClassName()` not `getElementsByID` since the word `movimiento` is in `<li class="movimiento bg"> Impuesto </li>`

```
Range("B1") = myIEDoc.getElementsByClassName("movimiento")(0).getElementsByClassName("l2 valor")(0)
```

Edit:

Check out the tag if the tag name if `<li>..</li>` so you should `getElementsByTagName("li")`

Check out the tag if the tag contain `id` `<li id="movimiento">..</li>` so you should `getElementByID("movimiento")`

Check out the tag if the tag contain `class` `<li class="movimiento">..</li>` so you should `getElementsByClassName("movimiento")`

Comment: now I'm getting error -2147467259 (80004005)'
I have references: Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library, Microsoft HTML Object Library, Microsoft Internet Controls, Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library, Micrisoft Smart Tags 2.0 Type Library activated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fixed that error, I had to restart my PC. However, now I'm getting error 1004 when running the code.

Comment: Worksheet was in protected mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select , try googling first and better start a new post for another question.

Answer (score 0):

It is faster to use XMLHTTP request as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://zonasegura1.bn.com.pe/TipoCambio/", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Debug.Print .querySelector(".movimiento .l2.valor").innerText
    End With
End Sub
```