# Runtime error 91 and 1004 VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, getelementsbyclassname

I'm new to VBA. I've been trying to get the value "3.2500" into cell B1. So far I'm getting runtime error 1004 and error 91 -object variable or with block variable not set- at times. What could be causing that? Its a Clean workbook.

```
Sub extract()

Dim myIE As Object
Dim myIEDoc As Object
Dim element As IHTMLElement

Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 myIE.Visible = False

myIE.navigate "https://zonasegura1.bn.com.pe/TipoCambio/"

While myIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
 Set myIEDoc = myIE.document

Range("B1") = myIEDoc.getElementsByClassName("movimiento")(0).getElementsByClassName("l2 valor")(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `.innerText` to the last line.

Comment: Tried it and get error 91 -object variable or with block variable not set-.

Comment: Why are you continually asking [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858435/getelementsby-extract-text)? What have you done to debug? Do you know how to debug? What have you done yourself besides asking the same question over and over adding a little bit from responses to previous questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getElementsByID("movimiento") is considering  class="movimiento bg" a match and there is no child element that matches so you are trying to get .innerText from nothing. You need the class name's second match and then locate the child or look for class="l2 valor" directly since the one you want is the third in the document.

```
'option 1
Range("B1") = myIEDoc.getElementsByClassName("movimiento")(1).getElementsByClassName("l2 valor")(0).innertext
'option 2
Range("B1") = myIEDoc.getElementsByClassName("l2 valor")(2).innertext
```

Remember that the index numbers of a collection of elements are zero-based so to get the third you ask for index number (2).

Comment: Amazing! Option 1 worked fine. Option 2 ,however, got the wrong number (3.200)

Comment: There are two class="l2 valor" before the one you want bo it should be myIEDoc.getElementsByClassName("l2 valor")(2).innertext

Answer (score 0):

your issue is:

```
 Range("B1") = myIEDoc.getElementsByClassName("movimiento")(0).getElementsByClassName("l2 valor")(0)
```

Is ambiguous. You need to fully specify where what is going. "Range this or that" is meaningless if you dont say what workbook or what worksheet they go into.