# Getting runtime error 1004, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm a bit new to excel VBA, and I'm creating a macro to run on financial worksheets. I want to shift the values in the totals to the right place, as they are a column to the left of the actual data (these weren't created by a formula, they were generated by a different program and are fixed text). The shifting I managed to do just fine. The problem here is finding where the totals column is, as it varies between worksheets.

This is what I have so far.

```
 For totalRow = 7 To 2000
    With ws
        If ws.Visible = True Then
            If InStr(Range(totalRow, "A").Value, "Totals:") > 0 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next totalRow
```

Yet for some reason, it's giving me an error when I try to run it. I know it's probably something simple I'm overlooking, because I cannot for the life of me figure out the problem. I've tried using a Do-Until loop, same issue. Is it a problem with the variables I'm using?

Comment: `InStr(ws.Range(totalRow, "A").Value...`  You should always scope your Range/Cells calls with a worksheet object, otherwise they will reference whatever happens to be the Activesheet.

Comment: Root cause: `Range(totalRow, "A")` is invalid syntax.  Use `ws.Cells(totalRow, "A")` or `ws.Range("A" & totalRow)`

Answer (score -1):

Several suggestions:

1. This is the basic problem:

> > Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

2. Look here for several potential issues/potential fixes:

[VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when Selecting Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select)

3. Use the VBA debugger and step through your macro a line at a time, until you find the specific object it's barfing on:

   - https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/vba_debug2013.php

EDIT:

4. Having said that, I think Tim Williams's suggestion is probably spot-on:

> You should always scope your Range/Cells calls with a worksheet
>   object, otherwise they will reference whatever happens to be the
>   Activesheet.

But PLEASE:

If at all possible, make the effort to learn troubleshooting tools available to you (like the debugger).

One other "useful tips" link I'd urge you to look at:

http://www.jlathamsite.com/Teach/VBA/WritingBulletProofCode.pdf