# VBA code with potentially corrupted files

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code. I took it from MRexcel, it seems they aren't interested in helping further. I have been trying various solutions with no luck. I believe some of the files to be corrupt in a way that does not allow the macro to run properly. Its basically looping through a folder and combining all the data into one spreadsheet. Its doing two things that are wrong.

1. It is only pulling through filtered data in the file. I need it to pull all data regardless of filter.
2. It is not pulling every file that in the folder, if I take the data of that file and save it over a good file that does pull through, then the data pulls through just fine. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is what I have so far.

```vb
Sub combine_multiple_workbooks()
  Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
  Dim sFile As Variant, sPath As String, LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long
  Dim sh As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
  Set sh1 = wb1.Sheets("Summary")
  sh1.Cells.ClearContents
  sh1.Range("A1").Value = "File"
  sPath = "C:\Users\jordan.burch.ctr\Desktop\TEST\"
  sFile = Dir(sPath & "Phase1*.xls*")
  On Error Resume Next
  Do While sFile <> ""
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=sPath & sFile, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData
    For Each sh In wb2.Sheets
      If sh.Visible = -1 Then
        Set sh2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    LastRow2 = sh2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow1 = sh1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    sh2.Range("A2:AE" & LastRow2).Copy
    sh1.Range("B" & LastRow1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    sh1.Range("A" & LastRow1).Resize(LastRow2 - 1).Value = sFile

    wb2.Close False
    sFile = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

ANy help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried to use the debugger and stepping through to see where it fails? I am assuming that in issue you are referring to filters in an Excel sheet. You can use <On Error Resume Next sh2.ShowAllData On Error GoTo 0>. For question 2, it may sound like a dumb question but are all of the files that you have in teh folder following the correct naming conventions of sPath and sFile that you have?

Comment: thanks for your response. Thanks for the welcoming!

Comment: sh1.Range("A" & LastRow1).Resize(LastRow2 - 1).Value = sFile

Comment: run time error 1004 aplication defined or object defined error

Comment: ok so will that code pull in all data even if its filtered? Thats what I am looking for. Yes all the files have the correct path and naming convention. Its just like there is a bug in three of them. If I literally copy the data from the file that its not pulling in then paste it into a workbook that it is pullling it it pulls that data perfectly.

Comment: All that code does is remove the filter. So you could then copy it if it is filtered. When you get the error, what line of code does it stop on? This is where using the debugger comes in handy. That error could be caused by a few things see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select

Comment: it stops on the fifth line from the bottom. I posted the line it actually stops on above. Let me know if you cant see it I will repost.

Comment: If `sh2` has a filter applied, you must remove the filter before coping it. Also, If you are inserting the file name into each cell in `Column A`, then I would use `wb2.Name` not `sFile`

Comment: Check the value of `LastRow2` when it errors.  If it's `1` you try to `.Resize(0)` which will cause a error.

Comment: You have a `On Error Resume Next` with no `On Error GoTo 0`.  That will hide all errors, which might be why some files arn't processed.  Either remove it or tightly wrap it around the line that might error and then handle that error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `For Each sh In wb2.Sheets` loop? As written it tests if there is at least one visible sheet in `wb2`, which will alawys be true, as a workbook _must_ have at least one visible worksheet. And it always returns `wb2.Sheets(1)` regardless of which sheet is visible, and regardless of if `Sheet(1)` is visible.

Comment: with that there are some hidden and very hidden worksheets and so it wasnt pulling through since the first sheet was very hidden.

Comment: You have a On Error Resume Next with no On Error GoTo 0. That will hide all errors, which might be why some files arn't processed. Either remove it or tightly wrap it around the line that might error and then handle that error. so with this when I remove it it just gives me that error on that line. I just put it in there to make it run all the way through since ive had multiple issues.

Comment: Check the value of LastRow2 when it errors. If it's 1 you try to .Resize(0) which will cause a error. – chris neilsen 17 hours ago. So this was right. It now pulls those files through correctly. The last issues I am having is that it wont pull filtered data through and I am not sure of where nor how to put that code in there. Can you guys help me with that?