# Object defined error when defining variable as sum of the values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I put together part of a script that will delete the last row if the sum of a set of values matches the total at the last row of that column.  However I am receiving an object defined application error when running the following:

```
Dim number As Double
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 36).End(xlUp).Row

number = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 36), Cells(lRow - 1, 36)))

If number = lRow Then

Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Delete
End If
```

This seems to work with `If number = range("A1")` as a test but not with these variables.
Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `lRow` when it fails?

Comment: Is your macro running at the worksheet level? If so, [take a look at some of the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select). Might help you out

Comment: The point of the above two comments seems to be that lRow must be 0. @Tim Williams points out that `Cells(lRow - 1, 36)` will cause an error if lRow < 2. @Allen W. Marx implies that your code doesn't specify the sheet on which lRow is determined. Therefore it is the `ActiveSheet`, meaning the last one you looked at before switching to VBE. That sheet could easily be in quite a different workbook or any other one you haven't in mind.

Comment: Well said @Variatus! Personally I would end up just using an if/else for this case. ``If lRow = 1 then Cells(lRow, 36) `` ``ElseIf lRow > 1 then cells(lRow - 1, 36)``   Are there better ways to go about this?

Comment: After the line `lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 36).End(xlUp).Row` what if you put, `If LRow =1 Then Exit Sub`? Also it would be a advisable to fully qualify your objects as @Variatus mentioned

Comment: @TimWilliams Trying to define ````1row```` as the last row in column 36 by going to the end of the column and then up to the next cell with a value. There seems to be a problem with the line of code when defining `````number````

Comment: @Variatus Thanks. The error seems to be when defining ``` number ````

Comment: Before the row where you define `number`, add a line `MsgBox lRow`. Commenters here think that MsgBox will show "1" when you run the code (because row 36 is blank or has data only in row 1). Of course, if lRow = 1 then `Cells(lRow - 1, 36)` in the next row must fail because `lRow - 1` = 0 and `Cells(0, 36)` is an impossible address.

Comment: What does it mean when number = 0, number = 1 etc.?

Comment: Also, I am attempting to prompt a message box...    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRYSS.png