# Relocating objects in a Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use the loop for the quick relocation of my objects in the different parts of the worksheet.

[image]

Each of my textbox have its own name (ID), which has been used in the loop.

The code looks as follows:

```
 Dim i As Long, shp, ws As Worksheet

         Set ws = ActiveSheet

         For i = 1 To 4

          Set shp = ws.Shapes("Textbox_Chamber" & i)

          With ws.Range("C6").Offset(i - 10, 0)
            shp.Top = .Top
            shp.Left = .Left
         End With

       Next i

   End Sub
```

The query below states:

[VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when Selecting Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select)

that one of the solutions is a clear definition of the sheet, which we are using in our operation.
My sheet has been also defined.

To be honest I don't know what I did wrong here.
I want to have this loop working.

**EDIT:**

After the advice in the comment my code looks as follows now:

```
  Dim i As Long, shp, ws As Worksheet

         Set ws = ActiveSheet

         For i = 1 To 4

          Set shp = ws.Shapes("Textbox_Chamber" & i)

          With ws.Range("C6").Offset(i + 10, 0)
            shp.Top = .Top
            shp.Left = .Left
         End With

       Next i

    End Sub
```

But it still doesn't solve my problem, since all objects are copied in one target cell instead of 4.

I want to have them located every 10 cells in the row like in the picture below. How can I expand my loop then?

[image]

Comment: You cannot offset 9 rows above C6.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my question recently. Is it possible to make more target cells instead of 1?

Comment: Your edited code is exactly the same as the original.

Comment: UPS you are right. I have fixed it. Do you know the second part of the answer? I am cordially appreciating.

Comment: Try `Offset(i * 10, 0)` but you might have to control the size of your textboxes.

Comment: It's good, although they start like 10 cells down fromt he target. Whereas the target for the first cell ic C6, they start from C16.

Comment: Solved Pal! It must be ((i * 10) -10

Answer (score 0):

The proper loop should look like this:

```
  Dim i As Long, Shp, Ws As Worksheet

      Set Ws = ActiveSheet

      For i = 1 To 4

        Set Shp = Ws.Shapes("Textbox_Chamber" & i)

        With Ws.Range("C6").Offset((i * 10) - 10, 0)
            Shp.Top = .Top
            Shp.Left = .Left
        End With

     Next i
```

Where, like the @SJR said in the comment, we must write `i * 10` instead of `i + 10.` 
The `i + 10` statement will place all our shapes in one target sheet, which we don't want
The `i * 10` statement will place our shapes correctly (each shape every 10 cells down), but they will appear 10 cells ahead from our initial target cell.
The `(i * 10) -10` statement is the ultimate solution for this problem, targeting our first shjape exactly, where we want, and next ones every 10 cells down.