# Find all option for one column only

Tags: excel, vba, find

Good morning,

I am trying to narrow down my find all search option in VBA Excel.
The original example comes from this link:

https://www.excelcampus.com/tools/find-all-vba-form-for-excel/

where you can download the files with the find all tool both for active worksheet as well as a whole workbook.
I would like to set it in the custom worksheet instead of the active one.

According to the hint based in the comment:

> Go to line 46 in the code “Set SearchRange =
>   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells”
>   6. Change this to “Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))”

https://www.excelcampus.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Find-All-Form-Search-1st-Column.png

I should only replace the SearchRange variable.

I did it, making my whole code like this:

```
 Sub FindAllMatches()
 'Find all matches on activesheet
 'Called by: TextBox_Find_KeyUp event

 Dim SearchRange As Range
 Dim FindWhat As Variant
 Dim FoundCells As Range
 Dim FoundCell As Range
 Dim arrResults() As Variant
 Dim lFound As Long
 Dim lSearchCol As Long
 Dim lLastRow As Long

   If Len(f_FindAll.TextBox_Find.Value) > 1 Then 'Do search if text in find box is longer than 1 character.

       Set SearchRange = Sheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
      'Set SearchRange = Activesheet.UsedRange.Cells - original input

    FindWhat = f_FindAll.TextBox_Find.Value
    'Calls the FindAll function
    Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                            FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)
    If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        ReDim arrResults(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
        arrResults(1, 1) = "No Results"
    Else
        'Add results of FindAll to an array
        ReDim arrResults(1 To FoundCells.Count, 1 To 2)
        lFound = 1
        For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
            arrResults(lFound, 1) = FoundCell.Value
            arrResults(lFound, 2) = FoundCell.Address
            lFound = lFound + 1
        Next FoundCell
    End If

    'Populate the listbox with the array
    Me.ListBox_Results.List = arrResults

  Else
    Me.ListBox_Results.Clear
  End If

  End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

I am getting the following error:

**Application-defined or object-defined error**

pointing exactly the line, which was changed:

```
 Set SearchRange = Sheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
```

Everything is alright when the one looks like this:

```
    Set SearchRange = Sheets("Tracker").UsedRange.Cells
```

so I don't know where might be the problem.

From the thread here:

[VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when Selecting Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select)

I can guess, that my form is placed in the wrong worksheet (as you can see on the image above).
In this event I tried to change the 93rd line of code:

```
   ActiveSheet.Range(strAddress).Select
```

to

```
   Sheets("Tracker").Range(strAddress).Select
```

but the result is exactly the same.

I also tried to set the different range for my cells:

```
   Set SearchRange = Sheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
```

as my data starts from the column A4. Unfortunately still no result.
I believe, that my problem starts from the `.Range` statement. When I change the `.Range` to `.Usedrange` 
then my error is:

**Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment**

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see is that the rowcount is done on the active sheet instead of the sheet 'tracker'

try changing

```
Set SearchRange = Sheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
```

to

```
With Sheets("Tracker")
   Set SearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Cells(1, .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
End With
```

edit 5-6-2020 tested the code and realised that the format was incorrect.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar did you copy/paste the exact code? It is unlikely cause any error.

Comment: Yes I transfered the .bas and .frm file into my work. I just wanted to narrow down the search to a specified sheet and specified column. I have managed with the specified sheet, but in case of the column I am getting this error, unless I set sth like this: Set SearchRange = Sheets("Tracker").Range("A4:A4000") , what can work but only within this fixed value. It's just an alternative - sweeping the problem under the rug.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar My question is: did you copy the exact replacement code from this answer to your project? There is no way this 3 lines of code produce 1004 error.

Comment: Yes I did. If you are saying so, I can try to do it again then.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar I tested the code myself and found that it sometimes gives a error. The new code should work in all conditions.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will give it a go later :)

Answer (score 0):

We can alternatively set the fixed range instead and see this problem off

In place of

```
   Set SearchRange = Sheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
```

We can input

```
   Set SearchRange = Sheets("Tracker").Range("A4:A4000")
```

However, it obligates us to take control of our range and keep the code updated as the amount our records is expanded.