# How to resolve Custom Sort Runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to sort my rows according to the Status (B), according to a custom order. I used to have Status in A, and the code worked fine, but then wanted to add an additional column before it and everything's been scuppered. Now getting a 1004 error.

My table spans A:L. Here's the code:

```
Sub custom_sort()
    Dim vCustom_Sort As Variant, rr As Long

    vCustom_Sort = Array("Published", "Submitted", "Distributed", "Amending", "Awaiting Sign-off", "Materials Drafting", "Working Up", "Arranging Interview", "Sourcing Information/Images", "Confirmed", "Pitched", "On Hold", "Archive")
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=vCustom_Sort

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Activity")
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        rr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A2:L" & rr)
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
                        OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1

        End With
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    End With

End Sub
```

[Screenshot of spreadsheet reflecting problem described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFyj5.jpg)

Comment: I've tried to change `Key1:=.Columns(1)` -> `Key1:=.Columns(2)` and also change `.Cells.Sort` -> `.Sort` but OP still have "1004 error".

Comment: Screenshot added. I don't know if it's useful knowledge - B is populated with drop lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error implies that it can't find a range to work with.
As we are working with a table, the `.Columns(2)` wont work.

This part hints that you have a table that your are trying to sort.

[image]

There's two approaches that I can think of now, to solve this:

**1. Sort a regular range by custom list**

We can remove the table by:

1. Click on the table
2. Go to design tab
3. Convert to Range

[image]

Then your originally code will work (Changed `Key1:=.Columns(2)`):

```
Sub custom_sort()
    Dim vCustom_Sort As Variant, rr As Long

    vCustom_Sort = Array("Published", "Submitted", "Distributed", "Amending", "Awaiting Sign-off", "Materials Drafting", "Working Up", "Arranging Interview", "Sourcing Information/Images", "Confirmed", "Pitched", "On Hold", "Archive")
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=vCustom_Sort

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Activity")
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        rr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A2:L" & rr)
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
                        OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1
        End With
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

**1. Sort a table by custom list**

We can sort the table, but we need to know the table name + table column we want to sort.
We get the table name here (click on the table) and in my example the table name is `Table1`:

[image]

Then we can use this code (I have comment where you need to adjust the names)

```
Sub custom_sort_table()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim sortcol As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim vCustom_Sort As Variant

Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1") 'Set/adjust table name
Set sortcol = Range("Table1[Status]") 'Set/adjust table column you want to sort (i.e. table name + column name)

vCustom_Sort = Array("Published", "Submitted", "Distributed", "Amending", "Awaiting Sign-off", "Materials Drafting", "Working Up", "Arranging Interview", "Sourcing Information/Images", "Confirmed", "Pitched", "On Hold", "Archive")
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=vCustom_Sort

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Activity")
    With tbl.Sort 'sort table
        .SortFields.Clear 'clear previous sorting
        .SortFields.Add Key:=sortcol, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=Application.CustomListCount
        .Header = xlYes 'Ignore heading
        .Apply 'Need to apply sorting, otherwise it won't change sort
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. I tried it, though, and I'm getting the same error: specifically, Application-defined or object-defined error. I wondered if it's because I have too many characters in my array, but it's 208 max, which I don't think should be a problem.

Comment: Strange and really interesting. I've really try to recreate 1004 error which many time is that the range is not ok or the worksheet is protected/hidden. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select).. But your code looks very good and stable. I've tried to add/remove columns etc. and with the example in the picture it works.

Answer (score 0):

While the code I was using worked initially, I wanted to find another way of automating the custom sort, as this spreadsheet is being used by colleagues who have a very limited understanding of Excel.

I ended up sorting the table by a custom list, as suggested by Wizhi, but rather than typing out/inserting the code, I saved the custom list manually (without vba), and then recorded a macro, which I then applied to a button.