# I am getting a random 1004 error in VBA on the .Refresh BackgroundQuery:= False line, does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have tried rewriting the code, but it was working fine before I tested it for about the 10th time and then it stopped working randomly.

```
Sub Titans()
 'Select Titans Worksheet
 Sheets("Titans").Select
 'Clear Contents
    Cells.Clear
    'Import data from Pro Football Reference
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/oti/2022.htm#team_stats", Destination:= _
        Range("A1"))
        .PostText = "local"
        .Name = False
        .FieldNames = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = 1
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .SaveData = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False  ---> This is the line of code that stops it from running
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: See [VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when Selecting Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980854/vba-runtime-error-1004-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-when-select)

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your macro, it ran simply fine in my system (office 365). Following was the output.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7oCz.png)

I cannot figure out the error details as I cannot simulate it, but there is an alternative to this, you can load the web link in the web data connector and get the table.
As I see there are three tables on the web page, so the power query will recognize three individual table and give it as individual query. You would not require macro at all.